# how to upload multiple files in AWS server from python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i am uploading the single file in aws and DB, but now how can i upload multiple files in AWS and my DB
Here is the below the  code for single file upload

```
def upload_to_s3(filedata,folder_path):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=settings.S3_BUCKET_BUCKET_AccessKeyId,
                      aws_secret_access_key=settings.S3_BUCKET_BUCKET_SecretAccessKey)

    try:
        filename = filedata.name
        file_name, extension = splitext(filename)
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        timestamp = int(datetime.datetime.timestamp(now))
        curntfilename = file_name + str(timestamp) + extension
        isexist = False
        for key in s3.list_objects(Bucket=settings.S3_BUCKET_BUCKET_NAME)['Contents']:

            folder = key['Key']
            if folder == (folder_path):
                isexist = True
                data = s3.upload_fileobj(filedata, settings.S3_BUCKET_BUCKET_NAME, '%s/%s' % (folder_path, curntfilename))
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data))
        if isexist == False:
            s3.upload_fileobj(filedata, settings.S3_BUCKET_BUCKET_NAME, '%s/%s' % (folder_path , curntfilename))

        print("Upload Successful")
        return curntfilename
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("The file was not found")
        return False
    except NoCredentialsError:
        print("Credentials not available")
        return False


def upload_to_aws(filedata,filename,timestamp,company_id,folder_id,size,status,created_by,folder_path):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=settings.S3_BUCKET_BUCKET_AccessKeyId,
                      aws_secret_access_key=settings.S3_BUCKET_BUCKET_SecretAccessKey)

    try:
        #file_name, extension = splitext(filename)
        curntfilename = filename      #file_name + str(timestamp) + extension
        isexist = False
        for key in s3.list_objects(Bucket=settings.S3_BUCKET_BUCKET_NAME)['Contents']:

            folder = key['Key']
            if folder == (folder_path):
                isexist = True
                data = s3.upload_fileobj(filedata, settings.S3_BUCKET_BUCKET_NAME, '%s/%s' % (folder_path, curntfilename))
                uploadprofile(curntfilename,company_id,folder_id,size,status,created_by)
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data))
        if isexist == False:
            s3.upload_fileobj(filedata, settings.S3_BUCKET_BUCKET_NAME, '%s/%s' % (folder_path , curntfilename))
            uploadprofile(curntfilename, company_id, folder_id, size, status, created_by)
        print("Upload Successful")
        return True
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("The file was not found")
        return False
```

Comment: What's wrong with the current code?

Comment: hi @Marcin current code is  working, now i want to upload multiple files, current code is  also applicable for multiple files uploading?